# how to create a list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Running the following code:

```
$('<div>').append('<ul>').append($('<li>').text('text'));
```

I would like to have

```
<div>
 <ul>
    <li>text</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 4):

The order of the append functions is wrong...you are now appending the li to the div, next to the ul, not inside it.

This would be better:

```
var $myList = $('ul').append('<li>text</li>');
$('div').append($myList);
```

Answer (score 4):

`$('<div>').append('<ul>')` returns `div jQuery object` and so on. It is for something called chain of functions. Usually if you write in jQuery `$(selector).method(...)` it returns object you get by selector, so you can write `$(selector).method1(...).method2(...)`, for example `$(selector).css('color', '#555').text('hello')` it sets color to the element and then change text into it.

```
var div = $('<div>');
var ul = $('<ul>').appendTo(div);
var li = $('<li>').text('text').appendTo(ul);
```

Shortly:

```
$('<div>').append($('<ul>').append($('<li>').text('text')));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<div>').append($('<ul>').append($('<li>').text('text')));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the div and no need to have a reference to `UL` or `LI` this is a easy clear way :

```
$('<div><ul><li>text</li></ul></div>');
```

Comment: +1 this is the way it should be.. `$("aParentObject").append('some html');`

Answer (score 0):

It starts from left to right, so you append `ul` to the `div` and then append `li` to the `div`.
You can fix this using the following.

```
var $ul = $('<ul>');
var $li = $('<li>').text('text');
$ul.append($li);
$('<div>').append($ul);
```

or in one line: `$('<div>').append($('<ul>').append($('<li>').text('text')));`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/Hg5Se/)

Answer (score 0):

As i see everybody first tries to walk around than does the job wanted..

This is ur html:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>text</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And this is the code you should use

```
var MyString = "Write something here!"
$("someParent").append('<div> <ul> <li> ' + MyString + ' </li> </ul> </div>');
```

or just do

```
$("someParent").append('<div> <ul> <li> Text </li> </ul> </div>');
```

if you would like to add more than 1 list item than

with razor syntax and MVC:

```
var items = '@foreach(SelectListItem item in (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["MYItems"]){ <li> @item.Text </li> }';
$("someParent").append('<div> <ul>' + items + '</ul> </div>');
```

without razor syntax:

```
var items = "<li> A </li>" + 
            "<li> B </li>" + 
            "<li> C </li>" + 
            "<li> D </li>" +  
            "<li> E </li>";
$("someParent").append('<div> <ul>' + items + '</ul> </div>');
```

there are more than couple ways to do it just pick what you wanna do.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this

```
$("#Div_id").append('<ul>
                         <li>ListItem1</li>
                         <li>ListItem2</li>
                         <li>ListItem3</li>
                         <li>ListItem4</li>
                    </ul>');
```

like this if you put this append for an click event you can generate many lists as the clicks